# When deploying my app in flexible environment getting error beta setting machine_type cannot be set in an App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When trying to deploy my app engine using flexible environment then i am getting error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: 
The beta setting machine_type cannot be set in an App Engine Flexible Environment deployment.
```

My app.yaml is given below

```
runtime: nodejs
#vm: true
env: flex

# [END runtime]

network:
  instance_tag: app-tag
  name: network-tag

instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 60

beta_settings:
  machine_type: f1-micro

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IGNORED
  secure: always

# Temporary setting to keep gcloud from uploading node_modules
skip_files:
- ^node_modules$
```

Also can anyone please tell me what is the difference between `vm: true` and `env: flex` because both set app engine environment to flexible ??

Answer (score 1):

When changing from `vm: true` to `env: flex` you're actually switching to the latest infra version, see [Upgrading to the Latest App Engine Flexible Environment Beta Release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading).

The machine type is no longer configured that way.  Instead you'd configure a [custom instance shape](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#custom_instance_shapes) via its [resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings):

> Resource settings
>
> These settings control the computing resources. App Engine assigns a
>   [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) based on the amount of CPU and memory you've
>   specified. The machine is guaranteed to have at least the level of
>   resources you've specified, it might have more.
>
> You can specify up to eight volumes of tmpfs in the resource settings.
>   You can then enable workloads that require shared memory via tmpfs and
>   can improve file system I/O.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> resources:
>   cpu: 2
>   memory_gb: 1.3
>   disk_size_gb: 10
>   volumes:
>   - name: ramdisk1
>     volume_type: tmpfs
>     size_gb: 0.5
> ```

Comment: does `vm: true` means standard environment ?? i guess not